# Repulsion of electric charges

Tags: particle-physics, electricity, electrons, vacuum, ions

If a take a vacuum tube and put electrons in it and put a negative ion strip or something like that outside the tube will the electrons inside the tube start moving due to the repulsion of charges of same sign?
Note: Inside the tube there are no charges just electrons and outside its -ve ions so will the electrons inside move?

Comment: Why wouldn't they?

Comment: just to confirm because the ions are outside the tube and the electrons inside. But we know that like charges repel but this is a case of electrons and -ve ions then also will the electrons move?

Comment: @andynitrox  you answered the question. The policy of this site is to formulate the answer as an answer, not as a comment. There are many questions that appear as unanswered but when other users get into them they find out that the questions are in fact answered. Thus, for economizing the time of other people, it is a good idea to place the answer as an answer. By that, you would also get the pints you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving this from my comment to an answer) Yes, the electric field simply penetrates the glass wall and charges (the electrons) placed in that field will feel a force and move. The glass does not really interact with the charges on either side, so you might as well remove it completely (theoretically).

Comment: But what if i use plastic or any other type of plastic tube then also will it work?

Comment: Yes. It would not work with a conductor, youd be building a Faraday cage.